# Getting 404 error when trying to use slugs in Django

Tags: django, slug

I am using Django to develop a website, and need use slugs in URLs. When I use ids, everything works well.

I have done the following steps:

1. I have a model Posts:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, default='')  
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True) 
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_photos/', blank=True)  # ImageField для хранения изображений
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.photo:  # Если поле photo пустое, генерируем случайный путь к изображению
            random_image_path = get_random_image_path()
            self.photo = random_image_path  # Привязываем случайное изображение к объекту Post
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', kwargs={'post_slug': self.slug})
```

2. I have written the following in my `urls.py` and `views.py`

App `urls.py`:

```py
path('fitness/<slug:post_slug>/', views.show_post, name='post'),
```

Project `urls.py`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin 
from django.urls import path 
from immuno2you import views 
from django.conf import settings 
from django.conf.urls.static import static 

urlpatterns = [ 

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('healthy-nutrition/', views.nutrition, name='nutrition'), 
    path('fitness/', views.fitness, name='fitness'), 
    path('fitness/<slug:post_slug>/', views.show_post, name='post'),
```

```py
def show_post(request, post_slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post_slug)
    return render(request, 'show_post.html', {'post': post})
```

and this works well.

However, when I try to make some amendments to use these slugs:

```py
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', kwargs={'post_slug': self.slug})
```

```py
def show_post(request, post_slug): 

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post_slug, category__slug='fitness')     

return  render(request, 'show_post.html', {'post': post})
```

I get the following error:

> Page not found (404)
>
> “/home/tkzeujpw/blog/fitness/fitness-post-1” does not exist
>
> Request Method:    GET
> Request URL:   http://example.com/fitness/fitness-post-1
> Raised by:     django.views.static.serve
>
> Using the URLconf defined in example.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in >this order:
>
> admin/
> [name='index']
> healthy-nutrition/ [name='nutrition']
> fitness/ [name='fitness']
> fitness/slug:post_slug/ [name='post']
> ^(?P.*)$
>
> The current path, fitness/fitness-post-1, matched the last one.
>
> You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

The only thing that I changed was the `self.pk` parameter to `self.slug`.

Comment: Show us your project urls.py.

Comment: from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from immuno2you import views

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('healthy-nutrition/', views.nutrition, name='nutrition'),  
    path('fitness/', views.fitness, name='fitness'),  
   path('fitness/<slug:post_slug>/', views.show_post, name='post'),

Comment: What is immuno2you app? Does it contain urls.py file? It looks like your urls are mixed up.

Comment: This is a simple blog. I gave you urls py for this app. Do you think the problem is in this? I wonder why everything works when I use pk and why it doesn't work when I use slug.